# How do I plot a parametric family of curves given a list of parameter values?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I tried plotting the function shown below in *Mathematica*; however the plot showed nothing. Could you help me explain it?

Note that here D' = 1- x.

[image]

```
ClearAll[a, x]; 
parameters = {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1}; 
Plot[(1/((1 - x)*(1 + a/(1 - x)^2))) /@ parameters, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Function[a, (* your function *)] /@ parameters`.

Comment: Please, post code, not images and try to format your question as to present a clear, self-contained entity. Any relevant bits and pieces -- error messages, external definitions you are using are, of course, necessary.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Thank you, I will study it carefully.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, e.g.:

```
f[a_, x_] := 1/((1 - x) (1 + a/(1 - x)^2))
parameters = {0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1};
Plot[Evaluate[f[#, x] & /@ parameters], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(L\)]\)/R=", j}], {j, 
    parameters}]]
```

[image]

or using `Table`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[j, x], {j, parameters}], {x, 0, 1}]]
```